# и то это - is this a typo?

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

Is и то это in the following comment a typo, or a way of emphasizing **это**?

> Я от своих родителей, за все время пока жил с ними, выучил только "бляха муха" **и то это** было так странно, что я даже помню конкретный момент и место, где была произнесена эта фраза.

**My attempt:** During the whole time I lived with my parents, the only thing I learned from them was "бляха муха," and (even) *that* was so weird to me, that I remember the precise moment and place it was uttered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a typo, althogh a comma is missing after "бляха муха". `И то` here is a particle which shows contrast, your translation of it as "even" is correct. "Это" is the subject of the second clause of your sentence ("это было странно"). The point is that "бляха муха" is one of the most mild swearwords, but hearing *even* such a mild one from the parents struck the character of your story.